# Como quitar el '#' de un <a>

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo puesto almohadilla pues no quiero que se me redirija a ningún sitio, solo que parezca un enlace.

Pero claro, al hacer click, aparece en la ruta esa almohadilla.

¿Cómo la quito?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner un `return false` con javascript. ¿Pero para que quieres un enlace que no sea un enlace? Podrías usar otra etiqueta y darle los estilos de los enlaces

Comment: Como tienes tu etiqueta *<a>* ?

Comment: @blonfu Bootstrap usa mucho `<a>` como si fueran [botones](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags)

Comment: @PabloLozano Yo también he usado enlaces para cosas que no son enlaces :) Pero es posible que no necesite que sea un enlace, por eso pregunto

Comment: @blonfu es una lista de enlaces, creando así un menú de navegación.

Comment: Pero si es un menú de navegación los enlaces apuntarán a algún sitio

Comment: @blonfu La cosa es que todo el contenido al que se va a redirigir, está en la misma página. Mostrando un elemento inicial, y ocultando los otros.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema y no sé como solucionarlo, ¿lo solucionaste?

Comment: Buenas @Sandro, la respuesta de Hector Lara (más abajo) puede ser una opción. Pero también te digo que tras unos años de buenas prácticas, si un enlace no te redirije a ningún sitio, mejor valorar el utilizar otro tipo de etiqueta (button).

Answer (score 7):

El atributo href es opcional, la única diferencia es que el cursor no cambiará al ponerse sobre el enlace, y éste no se subrayará (sin href se considera un "anchor" y no un link), pero se puede re-añadir el comportamiento con CSS, si es necesario. Pero eso puedes aplicarlo a cualquier elemento.

Además href puede ser una cadena vacía:

```js
let link=document.getElementById('test');
link.addEventListener('click',()=> alert('Clickado'))
```

```css
.test {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

```html
<a id="test" class="test"> Esto es un link sin href</a>
<a> Esto es un link si href y sin CSS</a>
<a href=""> Esto es un link a nada</a>

<p class="test"> Esto es un párrafo que simula ser un enlace</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar **javascript:void(0)** en el atributo href, con esto no iría a ningún lado y tampoco va a agregar el signo de numero al final del enlace.

Espero te sirva.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `void(0)` para evitar el uso de **#** en tu `href` y así evitar el direccionamiento.